# asp repeater and jquery.dataTable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Maybe someone can help me. When the page is invoked, sorting, pagination, etc... are not shown. I only get this error in the browser: `TypeError: $ (...) DataTable is not a function`.

JQuery is binding in the `Layout.master`.

Sorry for my bad English; I hope I have given all the information you need.

asp:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
```

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                            <table id="nutzer" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Nr</th>
                                        <th>Kdnr</th>
                                        <th>Benutzername</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>E-Mail</th>
                                        <th>Wo/Bereich</th>
                                        <th>Gesperrt</th>
                                        <th>Details</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Nr").ToString()%></td>
                <td><%# Eval("ADRNR").ToString() %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Name").ToString()%></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Langname").ToString()%></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Email").ToString()%></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Wo").ToString()%></td>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("gesperrt").ToString()) ? "ok" : "remove" %>" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                <td><a href="UserDetails.aspx?nr=<%# Eval("Nr").ToString()%>">Details</a></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
            </div><!-- /.box -->
            </div><!-- /.col-xs-12 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#nutzer').dataTable({
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any other console error?

Comment: A couple of things to check - does the table exist when you call the datatables initialise code? Maybe try putting the init code inside document.ready.  Is the jquery file definitely loaded before the datatables js file?

Comment: document.ready had no effect and jquery is loaded, otherwise an error message appears in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code can some help.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="YourRepeaterId" runat="server">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="TableId">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr style="background-color:#1261A6 ;color:white">
                                                            <th>Column Name</th>
                                                            <th>Column Name</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblNoOfInvestigation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column2") %>' />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
```

And then add below jquery code.

```
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#TableId').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            scrollY: '60vh',
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true
        })
    });
</script>
```